# What is in $\mathbb{I} - \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, foundations

In the Wikipedia page for the [axiom of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity) it states that the natural numbers are a subset of the set that the axiom defines.   Then gives a way of extracting the numbers from it.  However I'm curious about these non numerical elements of the infinite set.   What do they look like and why are they in the set?

Comment: Can you please edit in a link to the Wikipedia page? (or edit in the relevant part of its content?)

Comment: The axiom of infinity states that there is an inductive set.  The set $\mathbb N$ is the smallest inductive set.  It could be that $\mathbb I = \mathbb N$, but that does not follow from the axiom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The axiom specifies some things that must be in $\Bbb I$, but does not specify that anything in particular is not in $\Bbb I$.  If you take any set $a$, it could be in $\Bbb I$.  Then all the sets in an inductive chain starting with $a$ must be in $\Bbb I$.

Comment: Oh I get it.   If you assume a is in I then it doesn't lead to a contradiction likewise if you assume a is not in I.   Having "Is this a natural number" be independent of the axioms would kind of be inconvenient.

Comment: I am not aware of the reason for stating the axiom this way.  What we really want is "$\omega$ exists".  Using this axiom plus separation as described in the article gets us there.  It seems likely that writing an axiom that guaranteed $\Bbb I$ was $\omega$ is harder, but I don't know.